# Java Sub Classing: Overriding and Making New Methods

Tags: java, overriding, extend, subclassing

Resources which teach Java seem to have conflicting answers on whether it's possible to both override a parent class's method and also create a new method from within a subclass at the same time. When I try the following:

```
class ABC{
     //Overridden Method
     public void disp(){
          System.out.println("disp() method of parent");
     }
}

class DEF extends ABC{
     //Overriding Method
     public void disp(){
          System.out.println("disp() method of child");
     }
     //new method in the subclass
     public void newMethod(){
          System.out.println("new method of child class");
     }
     public static void main(String args[]){
          ABC obj = new ABC();
          obj.disp();
          ABC obj2 = new DEF();
          obj2.disp();
          obj2.newMethod();
     }
}
```

java throws a "cannot find symbol" error. Is there something I'm missing? It seems strange that one couldn't do both at once and yet I can't seem to escape that error.

Comment: Are these classes defined in two separate files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a reference to an object, where the *variable is defined* as `ABC`, then you can only call methods that are defined on the class `ABC`. Even if the underlying object is of type `DEF`, the variable itself is defined to hold an `ABC`.

Try changing your code from this:

```
ABC obj2 = new DEF();
```

to this:

```
DEF obj2 = new DEF();
```

It will work because you are defining `obj2` to be of type `DEF`.

Here's another example showing creation of a string, first with a variable defined for type `String`, and another with type defined as `Object`.

```
String s = new String();
s.charAt(99);             <-- this is valid on a String

Object o = new String();
o.charAt(99);             <-- same thing, but not allowed on Object
```

A workaround would be to use `instanceof` to check if `obj2` is actually an instance of `DEF`, and if so, temporarily use it like a `DEF` by casting it, like this:

```
if (obj2 instanceof DEF) {
    ((DEF) obj2).newMethod();
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!! I was hung up on this for a while!

Answer (score 3):

Here ABC is the superclass and DEF is the subclass.
So when you do `ABC obj2 = new DEF();` , obj2 can access only those functions which are defined in ABC. As `newMethod()` is not defined in ABC, you can not call it using obj2.